# Scroll de uma div automaticamente usando CSS overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu fiz um tipo de typeWrite(Maquina de escrever), com html css e javascript . Eu coloquei um overflow: scroll na minha div onde quando ela quebra a linha eu queria que o scroll meio que acompanhasse o conteudo ,sem eu ter que rolar meu scroll para isso .

**Resumindo :** Eu quero que quando chega no limite dessa div , de alguma maneira acompanhasse automaticamente o texto sem eu ter que rolar com meu mouse .

[image: Essa é a div que esta com o overflow: scroll]

```css
//CSS
.display {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 180px;
    padding: 0px 30px 40px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
//HTML
 <div class="display" id="tela"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce deve usar a propriedade `element.scrollTop` e toda a vez que um caracter for inserido voce checa o tamanho da `div` e seta o `scrollTop` dela para o tamanho dela mesma.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

```js
var i = 0;
var objDiv = document.getElementById("tela");
var txt = 'Inicio kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk meio kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk Fim';
var velocidade = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    objDiv.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    //Seta o scroll da div para o tamanho dela proria
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, velocidade);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.display {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="display" id="tela"></div>
```

Comment: Achei show do jeito que voce fez . Mas tbm achei apenas 1 comando que faz o que eu queria que seria tela.scrollTop = tela.scrollHeight; . nesse comando a barra sempre fica pra baixo era basicamente o que eu queria . Mas eu vou apagar a que eu fiz e vou fazer o do seu jeito obg